# Time difference when sorting vector of structs

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures

I'm trying to sort vectors of 2 structs of different number of element:

```
    struct1 {
      int id1;
      int id2;
      string name;
      double ts1;
      double ts2;
    }

    struct2 {
      int id1;
      int id2;
      //string name; <-- this was left out
      double ts1;
      double ts2;
    }
std::vector<struct1> vec1;
std::vector<struct2> vec2;
```

When I tried to sort vec1 and vec2 based on `ts1`, there is a big difference in the sorting time. The sizes of vec1 and vec2 are large (>100k elements). Does the size of struct affect the sorting?

EDIT: my sorting function

```
inline bool sorting(const Type &lhs, const Type &rhs) {
    if (lhs.ts1 < rhs.ts1) {return true;}
    else {return false; }
}

std::sort(vec.begin(),vec.end(),
          [this] (Type lhs, Type rhs) { return sorting(lhs,rhs); });
```

Comment: What does your comparison function look like?

Comment: what time difference did you observe? Did you turn on optimizations? How did you measure?

Comment: Perhaps it is the copying of the elements that takes time, not the comparison. In this case, you could try writing your own move assignment operator `struct1::operator=(struct1&& s)` and see if that helps. (Or perhaps you should wait for somebody more clued in than I am to confirm that this is worth it. If I had more time on my hands, I would try it myself.)

Comment: I would expect the size of  struct to impact the sorting time as the bigger the struct the more time it takes to iterate from one element to the other (more datacache miss for bigger memory footprint)

Comment: Depending on whatever "big difference" means, It might be the fact that the assignment of an trivial struct `struct2` is much faster than manually have to call the assignment operator as in `struct1` for `std::string`.

Comment: @Jean-MarcVolle: I would not expect this to make a noticeable difference.

Comment: Why is the lambda in sort taking the arguments by value? *Copying* bigger things is definitely more expensive.

Comment: @all I have uploaded my code for sorting function, just sorting based on ascending ts1

Comment: Unrelated, but your `sorting` function could just be `return lhs.ts1 < rhs.ts2;`.

Comment: @cigien: I believe you might have spotted the problem! I suspect that every time a comparison is made, two new `string` elements have to be created, which is obviously catastrophic. Ha An Tran, try replacing `[this] (Type lhs, Type rhs)` with `[this] (const Type& lhs, const Type& rhs)` and let us know what you see.

Comment: @TonyK the difference is still there (by 7 seconds for a size of 100k elements). Maybe I could try to locate to other parts of my code

Comment: @HaAnTran, the absolute value of the time difference doesn't tell us anything! What is the _relative_ time difference?

Comment: @TonyK hmm, how could I measure relative time difference in this case?

Comment: Just tell us the time taken by each sort operation.

Comment: @Stephen they are comparing member variable `ts1` of each object which is a double.

Comment: e.g. "With string takes 7.1s, Without string takes 0.1s" is wildly different to "With string takes 10007s, Without string takes 10000s"

Comment: @JohnFilleau you're right, I just suck at reading code this morning.

Comment: @JohnFilleau: actually, no, they are not. See my answer.

Comment: @StephenNewell apparently *I* suck at reading code. Totally read it as two `ts1`s.

Comment: Aside: you could have written `std::sort(vec.begin(),vec.end(), sorting);`

Comment: Benchmark: A [copy](http://quick-bench.com/e4VJv_0eMSX0cm6YuQB2LiO7CXM) gives an almost infinite diff but a [reference](http://quick-bench.com/jVuIYH_pycJPo19z1ERGXaOXMQ0) gives a 4.4 times diff. Still much, but, worth noticing.

Answer (score 4):

Your sorting function is invalid. The way you have written it, it is possible that two structures are each less than the other. If this can happen, the sorting algorithm can go on for ever.

Instead of

```
    if (lhs.ts1 < rhs.ts2) {return true;}
```

you need

```
    if (lhs.ts1 < rhs.ts1) {return true;}
```

or possibly

```
    if (lhs.ts2 < rhs.ts2) {return true;}
```

Comment: or better yet `return (lhs.ts1 < rhs.ts1);` or `return (lhs.ts2 < rhs.ts2);`

Comment: Mentioning that the comparison does not fulfill the _strict weak ordering_ requirement of a [Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) function would probably be good. I wouldn't be surprised if a sorting algorithm could end up in an endless loop with `lhs.ts1 < rhs.ts2`.

Comment: @TonyK No need to scream, I'm on your side :-) I just don't see where you mention that specific requirement.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: I did mention it. I said "it is possible that two structures are each less than the other". I don't see that I would improve my answer by using the jargon instead, which the OP may or may not have heard of. (Oh, and the screaming was my finger hitting CAPS LOCK instead of Tab. Sorry about that!)

Comment: @TonyK :-) No worries! I get that you were thinking about that requirement. I was just suggesting that you also actually _named_ it and linked to it so that OP would be able to dig deeper into it.

Comment: I edited my question, this is actually just a typo I made. Sorry for the inconvenience :(

Comment: @HaAnTran It's good that you noticed. That little typo makes a big difference. The next time you ask a question, make a [mcve] so that the result you get can be reproduced by the people trying to help you. Your edit now makes TonyK's previously relevant answer irrelevant.

Sidenote: Just do `return lhs.ts1 < rhs.ts1;` - The `if` - `else` construction isn't needed.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The typo is in my question only. In my real code it's still correct. I will time my code and check the performance

Comment: @HaAnTran You must realize that people spend time trying to answer your questions based on what you publish here, not on what you have in your real code. The answer by TonyK is a perfect example. TonyK wouldn't even have written this answer if you had asked the question with code that could be used to reproduce the problem - the problem only _you_ see. We don't.